# Linux Traffic Control: What is the difference between qdisc multiq and mq?

Tags: traffic, tc, queue

By default Linux creates a qdisc `mq`. I am configuring it on my computer to change some parameters but I found that there are 2 qdiscs that seem to be the same: `mq` and `multiq`.

I can't find any documentation on what the differences are between them to know which one to use.

The only thing I have been able to verify is that `mq` detects 2 transmission channels while `multiq` detects 8 for the same device.

---

In https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/sched/Kconfig specifies `multiq` but not `mq`.

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to figure out the same thing, I think the docs just aren't very good....

Not sure if I got this right, but this is what I figured out:

- mq exposes multiple hardware queues (when the hardware supports it, which most modern hardware does)
- multiq creates multiple queues in software, on top of a single hardware queue. This would supposedly help because each software queue would then have its own qdisc lock.
- There is also mqprio, which seems to expose hardware queues like mq does, but also configure how the hardware allocates bandwidth between the queues.

I wish there were more examples around showing how these features are supposed to be used.